# Estimate parameters of three parameters gamma distribution

Tags: estimation, gamma-distribution

I need to estimate parameters of three parameters gamma distribution. Can anybody please give me a clue in which software and by which commands I can do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found the answer in matlab code:

http://www.maths.lth.se/matstat/wafo/documentation/wafodoc/wafo/wstats/wggamfit.html

I wish it would be useful for anyone who is looking for the same thing. The method is referenced from:

> Cohen & Whittle, (1988) "Parameter Estimation in Reliability and Life
>   Span Models", p. 220 ff, Marcel Dekker.